# Markdown: Reference to section from the same file

Tags: github, markdown, documentation, github-flavored-markdown

I'm writing a wiki in Git and I'd like to reference another section within the same page. I'm trying to reference a section that is within a drop down. It looks like this:

`<details><summary>Component</summary>` 
`### Section I'd like referenced` 
`</details>`

[Link to ### Section I'd like referenced]

Any ideas? Is this even possible in Markdown? 
 Note that this is within the wiki, and not a .md file in the repo

Answer (score 0):

In other Wiki engines, and I presume with GitHub as well, this doesn't work because the [disclosure element's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) ("drop down's") contents, and therefore the link, are hidden and the browser can't navigate to them. The best I could do is to link to something just above my [disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details), might even add a hidden one myself, e.g. `<span id="link-here"/>`